# BigInsights Example KnoxShell on Windows

Tags: ibm-cloud, biginsights, biginsight-examples

Trying to use the KnoxShell example from Windows (using Cmder as shell emulator). When executing the following command, the shell locks, no prompt available and nothing happend. I can only close Shell.

Is that specific to Windows?

```
λ gradlew.bat -q --no-daemon shell
This is a gradle Application Shell.
You can import your application classes and act on them.
import org.apache.hadoop.gateway.shell.Hadoop;import
org.apache.hadoop.gateway.shell.hdfs.Hdfs;import org.apache.hadoop.gateway.shell.job.Job;import org.apache.hadoop.gateway.shell.workflow.Workflow;import org.apache.hadoop.gateway.shell.yarn.Yarn;import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
===> [import org.apache.hadoop.gateway.shell.Hadoop;import org.apache.hadoop.gateway.shell.hdfs.Hdfs;import org.apache.hadoop.gateway.shell.job.Job;import org.apache.hadoop.gateway.shell.workflow.Workflow;import  org.apache.hadoop.gateway.shell.yarn.Yarn;import  groovy.json.JsonSlurper;import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;]
session = Hadoop.login( https://bi-hadoop-prod-xxxx.bi.services.us-south.bluemix.net:8443/gateway/default, user, password);
slurper = new JsonSlurper();
Groovy Shell (1.8.3, JVM: 1.8.0_51)
Type 'help' or '\h' for help.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
groovy:002> hadoop fs -ls /
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the example on a Windows machine and it also hangs for me.

I have updated the README to state that this example does not support Windows and also added some logic to the build script to abort the example  if it is being run on a Windows machine.